# Java program runs with Windows Command Prompt but not with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying out Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. I have a simple program:

```
`class Hello
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}`
```

I have Java version 8u102 on Windows and 7u111 on the Windows Subsystem for Linux. The program compiles and runs fine on Windows. The program compiles on the Subsystem but when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.unsupportedClassVersionError: Hello: unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

How do I get Java programs to run on the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: Compile with Java 7. You are currently compiling with Java 8, and trying to run it with Java 7.

Comment: But when I run `javac -version` I see that it's 7u111.

Comment: For future reference: the duplicate doesn't really seem to address the underlying cause of the OPs issue.  My guess is that the OP didn't realize that `javac` won't recompile files that already seem to be compiled, so although they thought they had recompiled the program with Java 7 some or all of the class files were in fact still Java 8.